# Unzip all the items from the output of rglob() method using pathlib module

Tags: python-3.x, zip, pathlib

I have a folder that contains zip files in subfolders. I want to unzip all the files using this python code. code shows no error but the files are not extracted can't figure out the problem. Thanks in Advance.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from pathlib import Path


entries = Path('E:\\Bootcamp')
for entry in entries.rglob('*.zip'):
    with ZipFile(entry, 'r') as zip:
        print('Check1')
        zip.extractall()
    print('check2')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extracted files will be located in the folder where your python file has been saved

Comment: Thanks, man wasted so much time on this.

Comment: The problem is solved the code was actually working. I was looking for extracted files in the target directory, while they were extracted in the folder where the python file is saved

Comment: It's better to delete the question since it has been closed